# How to name a team within IT organization based on its roles

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, computing

How would you call a team within an IT organization, which has very broad but relatively shallow knowledge about the specific product (compared to its developers) and is responsible for this product's (software) deployment/delivery to client, maintenance and support?

Comment: Sales team or Customer (Client) Support Team.

Comment: In my opinion, "Sales" would not be a good fit. I was thinking about "Customer Support", but this term would be too narrow for the activities performed by the team.

Comment: The best way is to check how your competitors in your market are naming their teams. The team name should be **concise** and at the same time it should specify its function. You can't name it "Customer Product Delivery, Maintenance, and Support Team".

Comment: I'd call it the "A Team", if it was mine.  (Ask the team what they think it should be.)

Answer (score 1):

I work in IT, and the roles you mentioned are performed by a **"Support"** team!

In the context of IT software and services industry, "support" encompasses the entire spectrum of Product (software/server/application) maintenance, both Product and Client Support(not to be confused with (end) customer support, which would be called *Technical Support*), Continuous Deployment and Integration, Upgrade and Patching and some other functions(It varies across IT service providers)

If you are looking for something more elaborate, then consider - **Application Maintenance & Support Team** and use an acronym - **AMS**.

Or as per @Rathony's suggestion, you could drop application(it's implied) and simply call them **Maintenance & Support** team

Answer (score 0):

In my previous job, in a software company, we had a whole department with
responsibilities similar to the ones you mentioned and it was called **Professional Services**.

Comment: Also **customer service**.